# How to generate custom sorted query string URL in Rails link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I use link_to helper in Rails 3.0.7 app with many parameters, it generates a lexicographically sorted url as probably mentioned in the to_param method for Hash in Activesupport documentation. e.g.

```
link_to "my Link", {:u=>"user", :q=>"some query", :page=>"4"}
```

generates

```
"/search?page=4&q=some+query&u=user"
```

but what i want is

```
"/search?u=user&q=some+query&page=4"
```

Anyone able to do custom sorting as supplied in the params hash to link_to or url_for ?

Unless I am missing something, this seems to contradict the example given in the documentation for link_to (either `ri link_to` or in file `/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:215`

```
  #   link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux")
  #   # => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&amp;baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```

Of course, I can do manual URL creation like

```
link_to "my Link", "/search?u=#{user}&q=#{query}&page=#{page}"
```

but that would be missing the 'Rails way' and has some issue in Escaping certain chars, so would be the last option.

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have a feeling that if the order of query string parameters are important, something else might be wrong.

Comment: to display from  more significant information to less significant one. user or query is more important than page when the url is displayed in third party context.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8 or 1.9?

Comment: Might be something you want for google analytics???

Comment: Are you sure you use 1.9.2? Because I can represent it only in 1.8.7. In 1.9.2-p180 everything is fine

Comment: ruby -v => 1.9.2p0. I will update to p180 and see.

Comment: @user458221 It is about being in control of presenting the information in as user friendly way as possible. _page_ should be the last or at least after the query parameter on url.

Comment: @kanny who are you "presenting" the parameters to? Users should be looking at your page's content for the page number, etc, not the query params.

Answer (score 1):

Digging through the commit logs of rails, it appears that *to_param sort* is being re-introduce in rails 3.0.2 or so. Here is  log:

```
 $ git log activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_param.rb
...
commit 10dec0e65e1f4d87f411b4361045eba86b121be9
Author: Xavier Noria <fxn@hashref.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 28 00:32:20 2010 +0200

    let Hash#to_param and Hash#to_query sort again

    This was a regression introduced in 5c858220085dc4ddc1bec496747059dfbe32f1da. We bring
    sorting back because people rely on it, eg for constructing consistent cache keys.

commit 5c858220085dc4ddc1bec496747059dfbe32f1da
Author: Santiago Pastorino <santiago@wyeworks.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 22 05:08:34 2010 +0800

    Hash#to_param is doesn't use sort anymore, some tests added for Hash#to_param

...
```

I monkey-patched the file by removing "`.sort`" and the order of query string is as desired. Could implementing a custom to_param be solution to getting a custom sort/no-sort query string? In that case, where should it be put?

Comment: I believe the sorting is used for things like action caching that includes params. It's hard to include params in the cache key if the order of the params keeps changing.

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but for someone else who comes across this post, using `to_query` can help. See here the [old docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/to_query) or the [new docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_query)

Comment: Unfortunately not true. to_query is aliased to to_param. The link you provided shows a `sort!` in its code snippet as well.