# Rails: control ordering of query parameters in url_for?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to generate a URL where the "p=1" query param appears at the end of the URL, like:

```
/path?foo=X&bar=Y&p=1
```

Is it possible to control the ordering of query parameters when generating URLs via:

```
url_for(params.merge({ p: page_num }))
```

?

**Update:**

I tried [ChuckE's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396395/chucke) [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668620/93995). It turns out that in Ruby 1.9 Hashes are already ordered, so the code in `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash` is effectively no-op'd. You can verify with Ruby 1.9 that order is preserved:

```
>> h = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
>> f = h.except(:one)
{:two=>2, :three=>3}
>> f[:one] = 1
1
>> f
{:two=>2, :three=>3, :one=>1}
```

However, `url_for` *still* puts the "p" param first. It seems that any potential solution will need to address how `url_for` iterates the hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further digging, I see that what's happening is that `url_for` is actually sorting the parameters by key lexicographically, independent of their insertion order in the hash. Apparently this is being done to aid caching, since URL params are often used for page cache keys.

In short, you can't do it without patching `Hash`, specifically, you need to override `activesupport/core_ext/object/to_param.rb` so that Hash#to_param does not call `.sort` on the return value.

Related question: [How to generate custom sorted query string URL in Rails link_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047402/how-to-generate-custom-sorted-query-string-url-in-rails-link-to).

Comment: When I arrived at this question, ChuckE's answer had 2 upvotes, although it didn't work for me. This answer (and the bottom of Caffeine Coma's question) explains why.

Answer (score 1):

First question is: why would you need something like that? The order which the parameters appear in the url in doesn't influence the way they are fetched by the server, since they are basic key/value associations. So, no matter where the parameter appears, it will always be recognized by the server.

Nonetheless, to answer your question, yes, it is possible. You just have to use ordered hashes. They are available through active support.

```
opts = OrderedHash.new
opts[:foo] = 'X'
opts[:bar] = 'Y'
opts[:p] = 1
your_helper_url(opts)
```

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: It's an um, "aesthetic" request by the customer (read as: SEO effort gone overboard). My sarcasm aside, the "p" is the page # of a paginated result set from a search. It (arguably) helps the user see at a glance that he's on page 5 (or whatever) of the results, if it appears toward the end of the URL.

Comment: Great idea. Did it work at the time? In Rails 4.1.0 (I realize this is a few years later), it doesn't.

Comment: Also, here's my reason for "needing" to order the params. I am outputting some iframe code that I expect a co-worker to copy-and-paste into Wordpress posts. The iframe's src will be the URL I'm passing parameters to, and I need to tell them "If you don't want param2, take out the `&param2=xyz` part." That doesn't work well if the order of param1 and param2 are reversed, due to query params with the question mark and ampersand situation.

Comment: Doesn't work in Rails 6.1. Say I have a humans table with age, city, and gender as columns and I've got a table displaying the records. I want the headers to sort the table in a specific order.  Say I first sort by age and pass in { age: :asc } to my path helper.  Then if I want to sort by city but have age as the secondary option, my hash would be { city: :asc, age: :asc }.  If I pass that hash into the helper with humans_path(order: the_hash), Rails will give this URL:/humans?order%5Bage%5D=asc&order%5Bcity%5D=asc  Regardless if I use OrderedHash or regular Hash, Rails alphabetizes the keys.